# Why do Google not optimize Date/Time construction in their front-page Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, optimization

In JavaScript, we can get a number representing the current date/time like so:

```
var dt = new Date();
var e = dt.getTime();
```

A slightly shorter hand way of doing this might be:

```
var f = (new Date()).getTime();
```

The most compact way of doing this is reflected in the following code:

```
var g = +new Date;  //11 bytes shorter
```

(See them working here: http://jsfiddle.net/es4XW/2/)

Now, when you search through the source code of the Google's front page, you will find the second convention used 11 times. Therefore, it appears that on each occasion Google could save 11 bytes – 121 bytes in total.

Compression and caching will play a part in mitigating this, but surely it would be worthwhile for Google to make this simple switch.

Compare and contrast this with Amazon’s front page code, who do use the third convention (though not on every occasion).

So why aren't Google interested in this optimization? Although 121 bytes is peanuts to most of us, I would have thought they would have been interested in squeezing every last bit of performance out of their front page.

Comment: Regarding the close vote. What is not clear? I am happy to edit to provide further clarification

Comment: voted because I think asking why *Google* (or anybody) does something doesn't fit here... A proper question would be: "what are the benefits of the longer syntax"?

Comment: note: `document.getElementById` alone appears 30 times, and there are a lot more dom functions, it would be easy to save ~500-1000 bytes by shortening these.

Comment: +1. Interesting question. I also think that "Google" fits here because a "Google like" requirement (huge load) is different than a normal website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say readability and thus maintainability over marginal byte savings.
Also, the first 2 options are future proof, whereas the third option is an implementation detail which might get changed or works differently across engines (e.g. Rhino, Node).

A 4th possibility to your examples would be to wrap the call into a function:

```
var now = function() {
    return (new Date().getTime());
}
```

Of course this only saves a few bytes once you call it at least a few times.

Comment: In what way is the third option implementation-specific? I would have thought that the behaviour when casting a DateTime to a number would be specified by ECMAScript. Saying that, I haven't looked... :)

Comment: I said it `might be` changed and is specific to the current implementation that automatically casts everything based on context. It obviously works in all JS parsers now, but who says because of some optimizations a strongly typed parser would not handle this differently. But right, I could have been more clear on that. :)

Comment: It doesn't look like they would care much about providing maintainable code to the end-user clients. But the 4th possibility is actually implemented: `google.time()`

Comment: Having this in the source would just mean that this is uncompiled code. The client has no benefit but the next editor of this code certainly has.